# AWS Route 53, naked domain automatically routes to www

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have hosted a static website on S3, with Cloudfront distribution using the "Hosting a static website" quick start option on AWS.

I added an A record (alias) to the cloudfront distribution for the apex, and added another A record (alias) to the same distribution for the www subdomain.

soyou.co redirects to www.soyou.co and fails with an error. The cloudfront distribution url works fine. I purchased the domain in Godaddy, and added the Amazon Name Server (NS) records in Godaddy.

Where could I be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the www subdomain you need to add a CNAME record pointing to your domain name. Delete the A record alias for the subdomain.[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Could you think of what else could be wrong?

Comment: can you share your complete Route53 routing entries after masking it.